# font color to the silverlightdatgrid cell of particular column while binding

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

i just want to apply font color to the text of a silverlight datgrid cell for a particular column  while binding the itemsource

how can that be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make that column a `DataGridTemplateColumn` and in it's CellTemplate have the `ForegroundColor` set by a binding with a ValueConverter that determines the correct color.  In your value converter you place the logic to choose the correct color.